# Как получить максимальное значение из свойств массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, как получить максимальное значение id из такого вот массива

```html
const data = [
    [{ "id": 1, "title": "Ссылочка" }, []],
    [{ "id": 2, "title": "Другая ссылочка"}, []]
]
```

Пробовал вот так

```html
Math.max.apply(null, data.id)
// и вот так
Math.max.apply(null, data[0].id)
```

в консоли --Infinity
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    [{ "id": 1, "title": "Ссылочка" }, []],
    [{ "id": 2, "title": "Другая ссылочка"}, []]
];

console.log(Math.max(...data.map((_) => _[0].id)));
```

Comment: Вы б ещё использовали какое-то нормальное имя переменной и вообще отлично)

Comment: А такая в коде досталась, менять не буду код не мой)) Спасибо за оперативный и правильный ответ!) Реально выручили, особенно по скорости.

Comment: @vollof я же не вам писал, а @user, который в качестве имени переменной использовал `_`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с применением метода `reduce()`:

```js
const data = [
    [{ "id": 1, "title": "Ссылочка" }, []],
    [{ "id": 2, "title": "Другая ссылочка"}, []]
];

console.log(data.reduce((a, b) => a[0].id > b[0].id ? a : b)[0].id);
```

Comment: Андрей спасибо, тоже интересный вариант